# Regex unicode chars in C++

Tags: c++, regex, unicode

I have the following part of a configuration file (for example, .ini file) that is corrupted and I am developing a C ++ application that detects file corruption, using regex, detecting invalid characters in my configuration file:

[image]

When I read this file, by using the istream, and storing into a string (sample) I am having issues with my regex implementation at myexpr that is somehow not detecting the file corruption. In this code, I prestored the read file contents.

```
TEST(Concept, RegexUnicode1Sample)
{
    regex myexpr (R"(/[^\u0020-\u007E]|(\b.*(Mensagem|Antes|Loop|Movimentar|\|).*)|\\[0-9]{3,4}/g)");

    string sample = R"(\025\003\003\000\032\347\061\f\002\002\207\351H\346\353\037B\341\177\250\264\202\004\236\227\265
                    \261;\227\346ocolPortSecure=0\nMultiProtocolPort=0\n\n[TCP]\nTYPE=TCPIP\nPort=6800\n\n)";

    bool status = regex_match(sample,myexpr);
    EXPECT_TRUE(status);
}
```

This unit test fails when I run and what could be wrong here? I tested my regex at https://regexr.com/ and there it can detect the corrupted characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Perl `/.../g` syntax in your regular expression. C++ doesn't support that.

Instead, only include the pattern between the slashes. Then, to search globally use `std::regex_search`:

```
std::regex myexpr (R"([^\u0020-\u007E]|(\b.*(Mensagem|Antes|Loop|Movimentar|\|).*)|\\[0-9]{3,4})");
std::string sample = R"(\025\003\003\000\032\347\061\f\002\002\207\351H\346\353\037B\341\177\250\264\202\004\236\227\265
                    \261;\227\346ocolPortSecure=0\nMultiProtocolPort=0\n\n[TCP]\nTYPE=TCPIP\nPort=6800\n\n)";
bool status = std::regex_search(sample, myexpr);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5n51z3

A caveat, though, is that the state of Unicode support in C++ standard library implementations is pretty poor. You might consider using a 3rd party library that supports UTF-8 out of the box if you need to match non-ascii characters.

Comment: It seems now that is working 100%. Thank you for the assistance. I also heard that the STL regex is somewhat bugged in some situations.